# Javascript to create an li and append to an ol

Tags: javascript, html-lists

I'm trying to use JavaScript to create an li and append it to an existing ol. The code I am using is

```
<ol id=summaryOL>
</ol>

function change(txt) {
var x=document.getElementById("summaryOL");
newLI = document.createElementNS(null,"li");
newText = document.createTextNode(txt);
newLI.appendChild(newText);
x.appendChild(newLI);
}

change("this is the first change");
change("this is the second change");
```

These should look like:

```
1. this is ...
2. this is ...
```

But look like:

```
this is the first changethis is the second change
```

I have created a fiddle at: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ahb8F/) . Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/inspired_jw/Ahb8F/7/) - jsfiddle

```
$(function() {
    var change = function( txt ) {
        $("#summaryOL").append( '<li>' + txt + '</li>' );
    };

    change("this is the first change");
    change("this is the second change");
});
```

**To use jquery**, put below code inside of  <head></head>

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: An answer should not rely on a library not mentioned or tagged in the OP.

Answer (score 5):

Just looking and this and can't believe it hasn't been answered without jQuery, so just putting it here. In Vanilla JS, you can do:

```
const ol = document.querySelector("#summaryOL");
const li = document.createElement('li');
const text = document.createTextNode(txt);
li.appendChild(text);
ol.appendChild(li);
```

or alternatively, by modifying `innerHTML` of `ol` node directly:

```
document.querySelector('#summaryOL').innerHTML =
  changes
    .map(txt => `<li>${txt}</li>`)
    .join('');
```

Answer (score 4):

> Try Below. It worked for me. Remove null from

```
newLI = document.createElementNS(null,"li");

function change(txt) {

    var x=document.getElementById("summaryOL");
    newLI = document.createElement("li");

    newText = document.createTextNode(txt);
    newLI.appendChild(newText);
    x.appendChild(newLI);
    alert('DONE');

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddle is not relevant to your question...

In your fiddle, it works fine but you should never have an ID that starts with a number.

In your question, `createElementNS` is pointless - just use `createElement('li')` instead.

Comment: It’s perfectly fine to have an ID attribute value starting with a number. See http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using jQuery, you can try this:

```
var item= "<li>" + "some info" + "</li>" ;
$("#items").html($("#items").html() + var);
```

and obviously appending to the list is another solution.