# How to append li and div tags to html using javascript dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a horizontal timeline where the new element needs to be appended as per requirement.

I need to add new li ,div tags to ol dynamically using javascript in below code
This is my html code

```
<section class="timeline">
  <ol>
    <li>
      <div>
        <time>1934</time> mycode
      </div>
    </li>
  </ol>
</section>
```

I am new to technology.
Could you please help.

Comment: post html code plz

Comment: [appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically creating HTML elements using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536596/dynamically-creating-html-elements-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

What you need can be achieved using those methods from the `document` object.

1- `let container = document.getElementById("YourContainerDiv");` which returns the container `div` element to append list items (`li`) to.

2- `let listItem = document.createElement("li");` which returns a new element of list item.

3?- `listItem.innerText = 'bla bla';` an optional step to populate your list item with data.

4- `container.appendChild(listItem);` which will add the newly created list item to the parent container element.

Answer (score 1):

In order to dynamically create and append elements we have to use below methods to achieve what we need.

1. `document.createElement()`- This method creates the HTML element with the tag name passed as parameter.
    **example** :create a **`li`** element:-

   ```
   var dynamicLi = document.createElement("li");
   ```
2. `element.setAttribute()`- This method is use to set attribute.
    **example** - `add id` in the newly create `li` tag":-

   ```
   dynamicLI.setAttribute("id","li1");
   ```
3. `node.appendChild()`- This method append a node to the end of the list of children of a specified parent node.
    **example** - add newly created `li tag` to its `parent ul tag`:-

   ```
   let ul = document.getElementById("dynamic-list"); // we get the parent node
   ul.appendChild(li); // we append the li in the ul tag .
   ```

So, below is the working code snippet, using step defined above:

```
  let ul = document.getElementById("Ul");  
  let li = document.createElement("li");
  li.setAttribute('id','li1');
  ul.appendChild(li);
```

Comment: very well explained. 

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

```
var ul = document.getElementById("list");
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("timeline"));
  ul.appendChild(li);
```

for jQuery see this reference :

[Javascript to create an li and append to an ol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107541/javascript-to-create-an-li-and-append-to-an-ol)